# 2nd law of thermodynamics violation?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

What if I assume an ideal gas in a cylinder having frictionless piston and perfectly insulated walls with a perfectly conducting base is kept on a reservoir at temperature $T$ which is greater than the temperature of gas.
The gas inside the cylinder would expand due to heat gained and the piston would rise in proportion to keep the temperature constant.

All I essentially did was describe an isothermal process which is mathematically,

$dU = dQ - dW$

Which in our case would be,

$dQ = dW$

Since the temperature stayed constant and thus the internal energy as it is an ideal gas.

Does it not mean that all of the heat that I'm supplying to the system is being used to do work which is a direct violation of the statements:

> All of the heat can never be converted to work.
>
> Or
>
> 100% of heat can never be converted to work.
>
> (Which is just one of the variations of second law of thermodynamics I suppose, nevermind if not)

Or is there something else I need to know.

Comment: The isothermal expansion is *not* a cycle. See answers to this previous question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/261094/

Comment: @GiorgioP why does it have to be a cycle?

Comment: @GiorgioP nope, I do not consider what I just stated as the part of some cycle but an independent process. So, I don't get why does it has to be a cycle.

Comment: The statement *All of the heat can never be converted to work* is true only if at the end of the process nothing else has changed in the system and surroundings. If, at the end of the process the is a piston at a different position (the volume has changed) nothing conflicts with the 2nd principle. Said in another way, only a 100%  heat to work conversion *in a cycle* would allow a perpetuum mobile excluded by the 2-nd principle.

Comment: @GiorgioP Alright I got the answer to my question, but didn't understand what your last sentence means.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion

Answer (score 0):

> The gas inside the cylinder would expand due to heat gained and the
>   piston would rise in proportion to keep the temperature constant.

The process you are describing is not an isothermal process because it appears that the external pressure is constant. For an isothermal expansion process the external pressure must be gradually reduced while the volume expands so that the product of the gas pressure and volume is constant throughout. That keeps the temperature constant. Per the ideal gas law

$$Pv=nRT$$

If $T$ is constant throughout the process, then given $n$ and $R$ are constants,  the equation for an isothermal process is $Pv$ = constant.

> All I essentially did was describe an isothermal process which is
>   mathematically,
>
> =−

That's the first law. Not the equation for an isothermal process, which is $Pv$ = constant.

> Does it not mean that all of the heat that I'm supplying to the system
>   is being used to do work which is a direct violation of the
>   statements:

There is no violation because your statement of the second law is incomplete. All of the heat *in a process* can be converted to work, but not in a cycle, per the Kelvin-Planck statement of the second law:

*No heat engine can operate in a cycle while transferring heat with a single heat reservoir*

The key phrase, missing from your highlighted statement, is "can operate in a cycle". The reversible isothermal expansion process in a  Carnot cycle completely converts heat from the high temperature reservoir into work. That is not a violation because, as @GeorgioP has tried to point out to you, its a process and not a cycle.

In order to compete the cycle Kelvin-Planck requires that some heat $Q_L$ must be rejected to a lower temperature reservoir. For the Carnot Cycle this occurs in the reversible isothermal compression. That leaves the heat available for work as $W_{net}=Q_{H}-Q_{L}$, where $Q_L$ is the heat rejected to the low temperature reservoir.

An underlying reason for the Kelvin-Planck statement requiring a second low temperature reservoir is that when heat is taken in from the surroundings during the isothermal expansion, there is an increase in the entropy of the system of

$$\Delta S_{system}=+\frac {Q_H}{T_H}$$

In order to complete the cycle, all system properties, including entropy, must return to their original values. Therefore this entropy acquired during the reversible isothermal expansion has to be transferred back to the surroundings in the form of heat $Q_L$. That occurs during the reversible isothermal compression and is

$$\Delta S_{system}=-\frac{Q_L}{T_L}$$

For the Carnot Cycle

$$\frac{Q_L}{T_L}=\frac {Q_H}{T_H}$$

Therefore the total entropy change for the cycle is.

$$\Delta S_{system}=+\frac{Q_H}{T_H}-\frac {Q_L}{T_L}=0$$

Since the reversible heat transfers also occur isothermally with the surroundings, the change in entropy of the surroundings is also zero.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have two small related questions. Is the following correct-1) in just an isothermal expansion of a gas, the gas takes in heat at a constant temperature and thus its entropy increases by $x$ but the surrounding heat reservoir looses the same heat at the same temperature thus its entropy decreases by the same amount $x$. Thus the total change in entropy of the universe is $x-x=0$. Is that correct? Then there is no violation of 2nd law as the OP states. Is that not correct?

Comment: 2) by the last line you just mean 
$$\Delta S_{surrounding}=+\frac{Q_L}{T_L}-\frac {Q_H}{T_H}=0$$...is that correct

Comment: @Shashaank (1) is correct provide it is a REVERSIBLE isothermal expansion. (2) Yes, because $\Delta S_{surr}=-\Delta S_{sys}$.

Comment: You say "Reversible".is it because the formula $dS=dQ/T$ is valid for only reversible processes and for irreversible processes there can't be any formula. If so , is the reason why no formula can be written for irreversible processes very simple. If so can you mention that reason because I haven't been very clear as to why we can't write down formulas for irreversible processes or why thermodynamic formulas are only applicable to reversible processes and not for irreversible ones

Comment: @Shashaank I say reversible because in an irreversible expansion entropy is generated. You can calculate the entropy change by assuming a reversible process and applying $ds=\frac{dq}{T}$. But for an irreversible process that change equals the entropy transferred plus the entropy generated. Take a look at my answer to the following question, in particular my Case 1 and Case 2 comparing the reversible isothermal expansion to an irreversible isothermal expansion of an ideal gas. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/530693/entropy-change-at-constant-temperature-is-amount-of-lost-heat

Comment: Many thanks. I understand this now. But I still think I have read that general thermodynamics irreversible processes can’t be dealt with the formulas in thermodynamics (the formulas of thermodynamics only to reversible processes). I probably never understood why this is so. Do you have answer regarding that here..

Comment: @Shashaank Give me the reference where you read that "general thermodynamics irreversible processes can't be dealt with the formulas in thermodynamics"  so I can see it in context.

Comment: for example my thermodynamics lecture notes state that we can apply the formula $W=pdV$ to only reversible processes and also the eqn $dU=TdS -pdV=dQ-dW$ is also valid only for reversible processes. The notes don’t mention why these formulas can’t be used for irreversible processes

Comment: @Shashaank $W=pdV$ applies to a reversible process if $p$ is the gas pressure. But it also applies to an irreversible process if $p$ only represents the external pressure. The equation for $dU$ (or $\Delta U$) applies to a reversible or irreversible process because $U$ is a state function and by definition a state function does not depend of the process (path) connecting two equilibrium states. So it doesn't make sense, at least to me, why your lecture notes say it does not apply to an irreversible process

Comment: the answer here says $W=pdV$ is only valid for reversible processes https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/369188/why-is-work-done-equal-to-pdv-only-applicable-for-a-reversible-process ( but I guess you are also talking about external pressure but it’s not quite clear to me what you meant ). This here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86478/is-the-equation-du-tds-pdv-always-valid-even-for-irreversible-processes says that $dU=TdS-pdV$ is valid only for reversible processes

Comment: @Shashaank The first link says $p$ is the gas pressure only for a reversible process and that the ideal gas law can apply to the entire process because the gas is always in equilibrium with the external pressure. Then the answer says: Therefore, for non-reversible processes, $W=P_{ext}(V_f-V_i)$ Now $p$ is the external pressure. So $W=pdV$ is the work for an irreversible process but $p$ is only the external pressure $p_{ext}$ since the pressure of the gas is undefined in an irreversible process.

Comment: Regarding the second link, I don’t agree with the accepted answer. I agree with the second answer. For sure $dU=dQ-dW$, which is the equation for the first law, applies to any process, reversible or irreversible. Now if $dU=dQ-dW$ for any process, why should $dU=TdS-pdV$ be valid only for reversible processes. That doesn’t make sense. I’m sorry but I have no more time to spend on this.