# Entropy change at constant temperature is amount of lost heat?

Tags: entropy

The thernodynamic definition for.entropy change is only valid for constant temperature. But when we heat up something and its temperature does not rise what happens then to the added heat. If we assume that the system has a infinitely high heat capacity then the heat added must be do something. But what? Or is it “hidden“ in the gazillion microstates and too small to create a measurable change in the average kinetic energy?

Comment: "The thermodynamic definition for.entropy change is only valid for constant temperature" we extend this the same way we always do. We break down the change into steps small enough that the change in temperature is negligible and then integrate up.

Comment: I do not understand your starting statement. Do you mean that the contribution $\delta Q_{rev}/T$ is intended at fixed $T$? But that is just the infinitesimal contribution to a finite entropy change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thermodynamic definition for.entropy change is only valid for
>   constant temperature.

That is not correct. A differential change in entropy is defined for a reversible transfer of heat as follows

$$ds=\frac{\delta q_{rev}}{T}$$

So the change in entropy between two equilibrium states 1-2 is

$$\Delta S_{12}=\int_1^2 \frac{\delta q_{rev}}{T}$$

Only if $T$ is a constant does it come out of the integral. But it does not have to be constant.

> But when we heat up something and its temperature does not rise what
>   happens then to the added heat.

In the absence of work, if the temperature does not change as a result of heat transfer it is because the heat capacity of the substance is very large compared to the amount of heat being transferred. The heat increases the internal energy of that something but not enough to be detected as a measurable temperature increase.  We call this something a "thermal reservoir", and we call the heat transfer process an isothermal (constant temperature) process. For isothermal processes $T$ comes out of the above integral and the change in entropy is the heat transferred divided by the constant temperature.

> If we assume that the system has a infinitely high heat capacity then
>   the heat added must be do something. But what? Or is it “hidden“ in
>   the gazillion microstates and too small to create a measurable change
>   in the average kinetic energy?

The heat capacity does not have to be "infinitely high". It just has to be high relative to the amount of heat being transferred. The relative heat capacity of a cup of water at room temperature to the heat capacity of a hot grain of sand is great enough that while dropping the grain of sand into the water increases the internal energy of the water, the change would not result in a measurable change its temperature. Yet the heat capacity of the cup of water is not "infinitely high".

> Thanks I understand the part with the heat capacity now but I don`t
>   understand why entropy change has a value and why it is defined like
>   it is.

Entropy, and the second law, was defined like it is in order to account for the fact that heat can only flow naturally from a warmer to a cooler body, and never in the reverse direction. The new property and law was needed because the first law (conservation of energy) and the property of internal energy would not preclude heat from naturally flowing from the cooler to warmer body.

For a description of how the property came to be defined, see the following: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_entropy

> If it is energy per kelvin lost to do useful work it would not make
>   sense to me. If I transfer an amount of heat per Kelvin then this
>   energy is now as internal energy in the system and I could use it. I
>   am so confused. What does a value of entropy change tell me really?

First of all, entropy is not “energy per kelvin lost to do useful work”.  It is entropy generated due to an irreversible process that results in less energy available for doing useful work. In going from equilibrium state 1 to 2 the total change in entropy of the system is

$$\Delta S_{tot}=S_{2}-S_{1}= S_{transferred}+S_{generated}$$

Since entropy is a system property, the total change in entropy between two states is the same for all paths (processes) between the states. For a reversible process, the entropy generated within the system is zero and the total entropy change is just the entropy transfer at the boundary with the surroundings. For an irreversible process additional entropy is generated within the system. *It is the entropy generated within the system in an irreversible process that results in less energy to do useful work.* The generated entropy internal to the system equals the total change in entropy minus the entropy transferred at the boundary.

An example for a reversible (Case 1) and irreversible (Case 2) isothermal process with the diagram below illustrates the how an irreversible process results in less work than a reversible process although the entropy change between the same two states is the same.

CASE 1: Reversible Isothermal Expansion

The process 1-2 in the diagram is a reversible isothermal expansion of an ideal gas (pV=constant).

For an ideal gas the change in internal energy depends only on temperature change. Since the temperature is constant, the change in internal energy between state 1 and 2 is zero. From the first law $Q=W$ and for one mole of gas we have

$Q=W=(RT)$ln$\frac{V_2}{V_{1}}$

The total increase in entropy between states 1 and 2 is

$\Delta S=S_{2}-S_{1}= \frac{Q}{T}$

Where $Q$ is the heat added during the expansion and $T$ is the equilibrium temperature of the gas and the surroundings.  Combining this with the previous equation for one mole of gas

$\Delta S=S_{2}-S_{1}=$ R ln$\frac{V_2}{V_{1}}$

*So we see that for the reversible process the work done is the sum of the light and dark grey areas and equals the heat added.*

CASE 2: Irreversible Isothermal Expansion

Process 1-1a-2 is represents an irreversible isothermal process connecting the same initial and final states.  The process is carried out as follows:

At state 1 the gas is in equilibrium with the surroundings as was the case for the reversible process.  However, instead of gradually lower the external pressure as was done in the reversible expansion, it is abruptly lowered from 1 to 1a to equal the final pressure. From 1a to state 2 the gas is allowed to expand irreversibly against constant external pressure $P_{2}$ and constant temperature $T$ (at the boundary between the system and surroundings) and allowed to re-equilibrate with the surroundings at point 2.

In going from 1 to 1a, because the pressure drop is sudden, there is no time for heat transfer to occur.  Consequently for that part of the path $Q=0$.

*The lack of heat transfer between 1 and 1a results in the lost opportunity to do work equal to the light grey area under the reversible expansion 1-2.*

For the irreversible process with the ideal gas, the first law still applies between states 1 and 2, so the heat transfer at the boundary equals the work done, or

$$Q=W=P_{2}(V_{2}-V_{1})$$

Which is the dark grey area.

The entropy transfer at the boundary is

$$S_{transferred}=\frac{Q}{T}=\frac{P(V_{2}-V_{1})}{T}$$

So the entropy generated internal to the system is

$$S_{generated}=R ln \frac{V_2}{V_1}-\frac{P(V_{2}-V_{1})}{T}$$

*Conclusion: Although the change in entropy from state 1 to state 2 is the same, less work is done by the irreversible expansion than the reversible expansion due to the entropy generated within the system during the irreversible process.*

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I understand the part with the heat capacity now but I don`t understand why entropy change has a value and why it is defined like it is. If it is energy per kelvin lost to do useful work it would not make sense to me. If I transfer an amount of heat per Kelvin then this energy is now as internal energy in the system and I could use it,. I am so confused. What does a value of entropy change tell me really.

Comment: @Martinsssssssss I will update my answer to respond to this. Please stand by. Are you familiar with the Carnot Cycle?

Comment: Yes, thanks in advance

Comment: @Martinsssssssss I deleted my answer  previously  because I felt it didn't adequately reply to your follow up questions. But I have revised my answer to hopefully better respond.

Comment: You answer is appreciated. Let me recall what I understood: Gas expands irreversible so fast that the heat transfer in that moment is zero and we could not extract energy from the gas and thereby work from the gas in that moment. After the piston moved away there must be a non-uniformity whitin the cylindre temporarily which causes energy dissipiation and thereby entropy generation which is transfer from directed kinetic energy to randomized thermal energy. This amount of worl that is now thermal energy is the amount of the lost work? And the lost opportunity to extract work is gone forever.

Comment: @Martinsssssssss The pressure reduction was so rapid from 1 to 1a that there wasn't enough time to extract energy from the SURROUNDINGS in the form of heat, not the gas. The energy equivalent of the heat that was not taken from the environment from 1 to 1a equals the light gray shaded area, which is the lost opportunity to do work.  Thus the lost opportunity to do work was caused by disequilibrium which, in turn, is the reason entropy is generated within the gas throughout the entire irreversible process.

Comment: That lost opportunity from 1 to 1a to do work is gone forever. When the gas expands  (piston moves away) heat is then extracted from the surroundings and there is now the ability to do work, from 1a to 2 as the system moves towards equilibrium at state 2.

Comment: Ok, i appreciate your answers but i dont get it. I have to know the microscopic details to understand how it works. It makes sense to me that we extract less heat from the surrounding and the work output has therefore the same value and, thereby is also less than in the reversible case. But when there is less heat extracted then there is also less reduction of the temperature gradient between system.and surroundings and the gradient could be used again for another system to be reduced by heat transfer.

Comment: @Martinsssssssss “I have to know the microscopic details to understand how it works”.  As I tried to explain, during an irreversible process energy is dissipated in the gas at the microscopic level due to internal viscous friction which dissipates energy that would have otherwise been available for work.  That’s what happens when the pressure suddenly drops. The dissipated energy not available for work is the light gray area.

Comment: Perhaps the following statement of what happens in an irreversible process, excerpted from Wikipedia (article: “Irreversible Process”) will help: “Some ‘transformation energy’ will be used as the molecules of the ‘working body’ do work on each other when they change from one state to another. During this transformation, there will be some heat energy loss or dissipation due to intermolecular friction and collisions. This energy will not be recoverable if the process is reversed.

Comment: Now regarding your following statement: “But when there is less heat extracted then there is also less reduction of the temperature gradient between system and surroundings and the gradient could be used again for another system to be reduced by heat transfer”.  I don’t quite follow. The “temperature gradient” occurs within the gas, not between the gas and the surroundings.  The temperature at the boundary between the gas and surroundings is the same throughout the irreversible process.

Answer (score 1):

If you add heat to a finite system, then, unless the system emits equal heat somewhere else or exerts equivalent work, then its internal energy changes, so it's impossible for the system to remain in the same state. This change of state is where the heat energy goes. It's temperature will usually go up, unless there are other simultaneous changes in the system, that can accomodate for the rising entropy. For example a perfect gas may expand in a isothermic process - that exerts work but absorbs heat; the energy of the gas remains constant, but the entropy grows.

However, if the system is very big (often approximated as infinite) then the change of quantities like temperature or pressure may be so small that it is negligible. Such a system can absorb heat without changing its state in a noticeable way. I's not that there is no change, but because of the size of the system it is dispersed so much that it often becomes irrelevant.

Comment: If I transfer an amount of heat there is a distinct change in entropy and it is in Joule per Kelvin. I do not understand this unit. I transfer soume heat to a system at a distinct tenperature. Then I have a value in Joules per Kelvin. To calculate for instance the Gibbs free energy I have to take it into account. But how can I assign a Energy unit value to an statistical increase in microstates. That means in my opionen for the increase in microstates there has to be soame  loss in energy available to do useful useful work which is given in Joule.

Comment: @Martinsssssssss The units of entroy are so weird because we've historically earlier arbitrarily decided to create a separate unit for temperature. Now that we understand the microscopic physics better, we can imagine that different units would be chosen. For example, we could arbirarily (but sensibly) decide that entropy should be dimensionless. Then temperature should be measured in joules, like energy. It would work just as well. It's a matter of convention, really.